# Track additional e-commerce data - Impact of x on conversion rate

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

A client of the company I work for is moving to Google Analytics from Coremetrics and want to track the effect of certain items on the product details page on the conversion rate.

In coremetrics, this type of data can be passed in the Explore attributes (part of the tag where you can add custom data) but I can't find a way to do this is Google Analytics.

Here's an example of what they want to track:

Some of the products pages will have a video on them and they want to know if this helps the conversion rate of the product.

So, in Coremetrics we would have passed this info in the Explore attrribute through the product view tag, the Shop 5 tag (basket/cart tag) and then to the Shop 9 tag (order confirmation tag).

How can I do this is Google Analytics? Is it possible to pass any additional data in the eCommerce tags?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics (at this time) doesn't come close to some of the more advanced features you get with a paid service. However, you could look into using a [custom variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) ([custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) in Universal Analytics) to provide additional information.

So, for instance:

If a visitors visits a product with a video, then set custom variable/custom dimension.

EDIT:

Appending a custom dimension to an Add to Basket event sounds like it would give you what you're after. Depending if you're using [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup) or [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#sendingdata), the way you pass it will vary. Looking at Google's example for the ga.js, looks pretty close to what you'd like to do (I made a few tweeks):

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
   1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
   'Product Video',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
   'Yes - {product}',   // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
   2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
 ]);

 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
   'Cart',          // Category of activity
   'Added to Cart', // Action
   '{product}'      // Label
 ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I have the set the scope of the custom dimension to be session, so it picks up eCommerce conversions?

Comment: Totally, session-level all the way. Unless you'd like to know if the visitor, during any session, viewed a product with a video.

Comment: But I guess this still wouldn't tell me if the user actually purchased the specific product they were viewing when the custom dimension was fired? Because if the user then views a second product without a video, and no custom dimension is fired, it will take the value of the previous custom dimension.

Comment: Would it be possible to append the custom dimension to a Add to Basket event that fires when 'Add to basket' is clicked?                          Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I've updated my original answer.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please Accept it. Accepting it will provide others with a clear example of what work vs. what didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, but I've recreated in for universal analytics and passed it on to the dev team.